# transforming photo.uri to base64 file

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, expo

I am unable to transform an image to a base64 string, how would I do this? I tried filereader, canvas, etc. Please help.

```
  async snap() {
if (this.camera) {
  let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();

  app.models.predict(Clarifai.GENERAL_MODEL, photo.uri)
  .then(
      function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

}
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: to pass into the clarifai api as a base64 string

Comment: Once takePictureAsync is finished all you need is the path to the file name.

Comment: photo.uri is the file path

Comment: Hey @Brad , i use firebase storage to save images , this way right? I just take a photo uri from picker and save it to firebase as image ".jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing your code whatsoever FileReader should do the trick. Since snap is an asynchronous function:

```
async snap() {
  return await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
}

this.snap().then((photo) => {
  app.models.predict(Clarifai.GENERAL_MODEL, photo.uri)
    .then(
      function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (item) => {
    console.log(item.target.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(photo.uri)

})
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'inputs.map')

Answer (score 0):

Just add a flag `base64: true`:

```
 if (this.camera) {
    this.camera.takePictureAsync({
      base64: true,
    }).then(data => {
            console.log(data.base64);
             });
      }
    };
```